# Doctrine2 native query does not hydrate custom type

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In a ZF2 - PostgreSQL application, I want to use Doctrine2 native queries to build paginator lists.

So, it works great if any custom Doctrine / Pgsql type is selected. But for one query, I would use data from a custom type.

I have a Doctrine 2 custom type called `AlertRecipient` declared in PostgreSQL such as below :

```
CREATE TYPE alert_recipient AS (
    email text,
    status int
);
```

This type is used in some tables. example in a `clients` table :

```
ID (int) | name (varchar) | alerts (alert_recipients[])
1        | John Doe       | {"(john@doe.com, 1), (jane@doe.com, 1)"} 
2        | Foo Bar        | {"(foo@bar.com, 1)"}
```

(`alert_recipient[]` extends `alert_recipient` to store a list of many `alert_recipient`records)

This type is linked to an entity, for hydration :

```
class AlertRecipient
{
    protected $email;

    protected $status;

    // ... with accessors
}
```

Doctrine type registration is made on the `onBoostrap` event :

```
// ...
if (!Type::hasType('alert_recipient'))
{
    Type::addType('alert_recipient', AlertRecipient::class);
}
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('alert_recipient', 'alert_recipient');

if (!Type::hasType('alert_recipient[]'))
{
    Type::addType('alert_recipient[]', AlertRecipients::class);
}
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('_alert_recipient', 'alert_recipient[]');
// ...
```

Custom type doctrine adapter has been written such as the doc http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

And the query looks like :

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);

$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(Client::class, 'c');
// ... some other data from join entity (e.g)

$query = 'SELECT c.* FROM clients c JOIN ...';
$em->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);

$results = $query->getResult(NativeQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Problem is I don't have the same behavior from a `find()` Doctrine native method, or from the hydration of my native query result.

Debug in custom type adapter :

```
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    var_dump($value); exit;
    // ...
}
```

**Edit**

```
public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)
{
    return 'to_json(' . $sqlExpr . ')';
}
```

From `find()`, result is correctly hydrated used the `AlertRecipient` entity :  `string '[{"email":"john@doe.com","status":1}, {"email":"jane@doe.com","status":1}]'`

And from the native query hydration, result['order_emails'] is not hydrated in the `AlertRecipient` entity : `string '{"(john@doe.com, 1), (jane@doe.com, 1)"}'`

Then data are not correctly hydrated ...

Thanks for your ideas

**Edit**

Declaration of `alertRecipient` property in `Client` entity :

```
/* @ORM\Column(type="alert_recipient[]", nullable=true, name="alert_recipients")
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 */
 protected $alertRecipients = [];

 // ... with accessors
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [Doctrine 2 documentation for **Custom Mapping Types**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)?

You should methods like `convertToPHPValue` and `convertToDatabaseValue` for hydration to work correctly.

You also wrote:

> From `find()`, result is correctly hydrated used the `AlertRecipient` entity...

As I understood `AlertRecipient` is a dbal `Type` class not an `Entity` class.

Type classes (so your `AlertRecipient` class) should extend `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type`.

Then you should in the entity definition where you use this type mark the column with the correct type attribute:

```
/** @Column(type="alert_recipient") */
$alertRecipient;
```

Since you didn't share all the details (entity definitions where you use your custom type for example) I am not sure where you go wrong, but if you follow the documentation all this should work as expected, so my guess would be you skipped one of those steps.

Comment: you're right about dbal Type, "hydration" is handled by postgreSQL. The related entity is used in `convertToPHPValue` method. In my case, for `find()` doctrine method, `convertToPHPValueSQL` is called (`return 'to_json(' . $sqlExpr . ')';`) but not with a native query ... I'm searching a way to hydrate the `Client::alertRecipients` through `ResultSetMapping` right, without hardcode `SELECT ..., to_json(alert_recipients) FROM clients ...`

Comment: @ceadreak What does the column definition for `alertRecipients` look like inside your `Client` entity?

Comment: @ Wilt please check the Edit in my question